# Change filesize unit with a tar command

Tags: linux, tar

How can I change the filesize unit that is output by the `tar` command?

```
tar tvf test.tar.gz | awk '{print $5,$9}'
```

I would like for it to print the filesize in Gigabytes.

Comment: A gigabyte is 1000000000 bytes.  Division of the file size in bytes by that number should give you the size in gigabytes.

Answer (score -1):

Very crudely, you could:

`$ while read size filename; do echo "$filename: $(( size /1024 /1024 /1024))"; done < <(tar tvf test .tar.gz | awk '{print $4,$7}')
test1.txt: 1
test2.txt: 5
test3.txt: 0
$`

You may also like to add some decimal precision:

`$ while read size filename; do echo "$filename: $(( (size * 100) /1024 /1024 /1024))"; done < <(tar tvf test.tar.gz | awk '{print $4,$7}') | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)$/.\1/'
test1.txt: 1.03
test2.txt: 5.93
test3.txt: 0.44
$`

Comment: Why those cumbersome `while` loops? `awk` cand do all that work, and the work of `sed` as well.